# How does Firebase and MongoDB Atlas Synchronise Time?

Tags: firebase, time, mongodb-atlas, data-synchronization

Does anyone know how the following services take their time references from. In other words: **with what source do they sync their time reference?**

- Firebase
- MongoDB Atlas

Found out that AWS services sync their time with a service called Amazon Time Sync.

> Amazon Time Sync is used by EC2 instances and other AWS services. It
> uses a fleet of redundant satellite-connected and atomic clocks in
> each Region to deliver time derived from these highly accurate
> reference clocks. This service is provided at no additional charge.

Likewise I need information about Firebase and MongoDB Atlas specifically. Any help/source is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What I found by myself.

**AWS Services** - AWS services sync time with Amazon Time Sync. It uses a fleet of redundant satellite-connected and atomic clocks in each Region to deliver time derived from these highly accurate reference clocks.

**Google Services** - Google services including Firebase use Google Public NTP. This is a free, global time service that you can use to synchronize to Google's atomic clocks.

**MongoDB Atlas** - MongoDB Atlas has been enhanced by a move to a global logical clock. Implemented as a hybrid logical clock and protected by encryption.

Since all the services use highly accurate time services, we can assume that they represent the exact time so that time is synchronized across all the services in one application.

***References***

1. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aw
2. https://developers.google.com/time/faq
3. https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/transactions-background-part-4-the-global-logical-clock